# How to make sure this JavaScript code can run within C# ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Needed help again

Is there a way to run this javascript inside C# ASP.NET coding instead of the HTML/ASPX files?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// document.getElementById("label1").
var input = document.getElementById('input-id');
var datepicker = new HotelDatepicker(input, {
    disabledDates: [
        "2017-07-11"
    ]
});

</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RegisterStartupScript` in the Page_Load or Page_PreRender:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),  
    "datePickerInit", "var datepicker = new HotelDatepicker(document.getElementById('input-id'), { disabledDates: ['2017-07-11']});", 
    true);
```